# splitting the file basis of Line Number

Tags: unix

Can u pls advise the unix command as I have a file which contain the records in the below format

```
333434
435435
435443
434543
343536
```

Now the total line count is 89380 , now i want to  create a seprate

I am trying to split my large big file into small bits using the line numbers. For example my file has 89380 lines and i would like to divide this into small files wach of which has 1000 lines.

could you please advise unix command to achieve this

can unix split command can be used here..!!

Answer (score 13):

Use `split`

Syntax  `split [options] filename prefix`

Replace filename with the name of the large file you wish to split. Replace prefix with the name you wish to give the small output files. You can exclude [options], or replace it with either of the following:

> -l linenumber
>
> -b bytes

If you use the  -l  (a lowercase L) option, replace linenumber with the number of lines you'd like in each of the smaller files (the default is 1,000). If you use the  -b  option, replace bytes with the number of bytes you'd like in each of the smaller files.

The split command will give each output file it creates the name prefix with an extension tacked to the end that indicates its order. By default, the split command adds aa to the first output file, proceeding through the alphabet to zz for subsequent files. If you do not specify a prefix, most systems use  x .

**Example1:**

```
split myfile
```

This will output three 1000-line files: xaa, xab, and xac.

**Example2:**

```
split -l 500 myfile segment
```

This will output six 500-line files: segmentaa, segmentab, segmentac, segmentad, segmentae, and segmentaf.

**Example3:**

Assume myfile is a 160KB file:

```
split -b 40k myfile segment
```

This will output four 40KB files: segmentaa, segmentab, segmentac, and segmentad.

Comment: i was pleased to find that `split` is included in my `cygwin` installation - +1 for this simple fix to a large file issue!

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use [sed](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?sed) command.

you can use `sed -n "1, 1000p" yourfile > outputfile` to get line 1 to line 1000.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `--lines` switch or its short form `-l`

```
split --lines=1000 input_file_name output_file_prefix
```